# Get list of items if they match a list into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which store data:

```
create table exchanges
(
    exchange_long_name  text,
    exchange_id         bigint
);

create table active_pairs
(
    exchange_id           integer
);
```

I would like to get the list of `exchanges` if they are present/match the `exchange_id` into table `active_pairs`. How this can be implemented using JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  distinct exchanges.exchange_id, exchanges.exchange_long_name
from exchanges inner join active_pairs
on exchanges.exchange_id = active_pairs.exchange_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I see one issue here. Result is repeated. How they should be made unique?

Comment: @user1285928 use distinct! Fixed my answer